# MYSQL - Removing number from One Table in SQL if it exists in another Table

Tags: mysql

I need some assistance with deleting data within an SQL Table if it matches data from another table.

There are two Tables

```
Table 1: DNC
Table 2: Call_Logs
```

Table 1 has only one column called `phone_number`.
Table 2 has multiple columns, but the main one that is important is also named `phone_number`.

Basically, I want to remove any numbers that are in Table 2 from Table 1, if they exist.  Now, I don't want to delete every number from Table 1 if they exist in Table 2.  What numbers I collect from Table 2 are based on some criteria.

To pull the data from Table 2 that I need to delete from Table 1,  I use the following:

```
select phone_number from call_logs where call_date < 'DATE' and Status = 'DNC'
```

This query will give me a list of all phone numbers that I would want to remove from Table 1 if it exists.

EXAMPLE:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4NE4ZDXd6steW5odWhBMDJSY1U/view

I am not sure how I would go about running the query in SQL.  Any types would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your sample in img

You could use a left join on table 2 (where table2.phone_number is null alias don't match)

```
delete from table1
left join table2 on table1.phone_number = table2.phone_number
where table2.phone_number is null
```

Answer (score 0):

correlated subquery w/ an exists so it can early exit

The `select 1` in the subquery is because we have to select a value but it doesn't matter what value that is.  since the coloration (DNC.Phone_Number = CL.Phone_Number) is all we are after; along with your limits on call_log.

```
DELETE 
FROM DNC
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM Call_logs CL
              WHERE CL.call_date < 'DATE' 
                and CL.Status = 'DNC' 
                and DNC.Phone_Number = CL.Phone_Number)
```